# Trouble Getting JSON Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift3

I'm having an issue getting a JSON array using Swift.

```
func getBenefitJSON() -> [AnyObject] {
        let urlString = String("https://www.kyfb.com/KYFB/includes/themes/CodeBlue/display_objects/custom/remote/webservices/services.cfc?method=getMemberBenefits")
        let url = URL(string: urlString!)
        var data = Data()
        do {
            data = try Data(contentsOf: url!)
        } catch {

        }

        print("URL Data: \(data)")

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions()) as! [AnyObject]
            print("JSON: \(json)")
            return json
        } catch {
            print("Could not get JSON")
            return []
        }
    }
```

I get the data from the url but get an empty array returned. What am I doing wrong?

```
URL Data: 42769 bytes
Could not get JSON
```

Below is the response of JSON

```
[{"image":"https://cdn.kyfb.com/KYFB/cache/file/70162997-E06B-E9B6-88514280CA8397CC_medium.jpg","description":"","link":"https://www.kyfb.com/insurance/insurance-products/","name":"KFB Insurance","children":[]}, ...]
```

Below is the error

```
UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

I've also validated the response from the URL at jsonlint.com

URL data as string:

```
<wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>[{"image":"https://cdn.kyfb.com/KYFB/cache/file/70162997-E06B-E9B6-88514280CA8397CC_medium.jpg","description":"","link":"https://www.kyfb.com/insurance/insurance-products/","name":"KFB Insurance","children":[]}, ...]</string></data></wddxPacket>)
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to actually catch the error to see what's going on.

Comment: Is that url reachable?

Comment: @RomanPodymov Yes, it's reachable.

Comment: How did you get the JSON your printed? Is it the full JSON from `data`?

Comment: @Larme By going to the URL in a browser.

Comment: The thing is that the length of the JSON you gave transformed into NSData is "222". Which is far less than "42769". So are you sure that your JSON is a top level a array? Also, printing the error when it fails could be a VERY good idea.

Comment: @Larme I gave the first item in the JSON array. I didn't want to put it all in my question because it's a little long. You can go to the URL and see the entire thing.

Comment: And what is the error in the `catch` then?

Comment: Your response is not proper json . It is xml : <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string>'your json data array' </string></data></wddxPacket>

Comment: Apart from the issue you should **never** load data with synchronous methods like `Data(contentsOf...`. This method is supposed to be used only in the local file system. Use `URLSession` to load data asynchronously. And JSON collection types are always `[String:AnyObject]` or `[[String:AnyObject]]`. It's bad programming habit to use the more unspecified `[AnyObject]`.

Comment: @Larme I've added the error to my question.

Comment: I can't get the data with the URL (blocked for me?), but @vishnuvarthan seems to say that's the answer is XML. So either your WebService if broken, or your request is missing a header (so use URLSession) to specify that it wants JSON. We may helps if we have access to the real content of data (after you transformed it into a NSString)

Comment: @Larme service is not broken, it works randomly.

Comment: @raginggoat print the data you receive as string and see what you have received before serializing.

Comment: The data starts with <wddxPacket version='1.0'><header/><data><string> before the array so I'll get that fixed.

Comment: @raginggoat I tried multiple times, couldn't get it. Could you show what's the data (converted into string), at least the XML/HTML part, where the JSON start (at least the start like your previously did), and the end of the XML, eclipsing what's needed to be eclipsed with "..." (middle part)?

Comment: @Larme I've added it. That appears to be the issue.

Comment: You could remove the XML part (before and after) if it's always the same (not recommended, but it's a quick hack), or use a (NS)XMLParser to get only the NSString of the JSON. Then, you convert that String (that represents the JSON) into NSData and call `JSONSerialization.jsonObject()` on it.

Comment: @Larme I'm just going to have the web developer fix it. :)

Answer (score -1):

I tested your code and it is working if the top level of the JSON is an Array. So the JSON you want to read is probably not an array but a dictionary.

To read the Dictionary you need to change the return type from `[AnyObject]` into `[String:AnyObject]` and all other occurrences of this type.

Nevertheless, I would recommend to use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON) for working with JSON in Swift.

Comment: I've added a portion of the JSON to my question. The top level is an array.